# Question of Permutation and combination

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have found a question from somewhere in the internet as follows:

> English language has 26 alphabets, out of 4 distinct vowels and 7
>   distinct consonants, how many letter patterns can be made with each to
>   contain 3 distinct consonants and 2 distinct vowels?

I can't find out the solution. Can anyone help me to find it out here?

Comment: It has 26 letters, not alphabets. Have you tried anything? Any thoughts you have? Sketch: How many ways are there to pick three consonants out of 7? How many ways are there to pick 2 vowels out of 4? How many ways are there to arrange 5 letters?

Comment: There are 7c3 ways to choose the 3 constants from 7 and 4c2 ways to choose 2 vowels from 4. To fill the 5 place, there could be 5! possible arrangements. So, the result will be (7c3) * (4c2) * 5!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per a lucid conclusion, I have posted it as follows [The solution have copied from comments]:

From @whacka

> It has 26 letters, not alphabets. Have you tried anything? Any
>   thoughts you have? Sketch: How many ways are there to pick three
>   consonants out of 7? How many ways are there to pick 2 vowels out of
>   4? How many ways are there to arrange 5 letters?

From @Me

> There are 7c3 ways to choose the 3 constants from 7 and 4c2 ways to
>   choose 2 vowels from 4. To fill the 5 place, there could be 5!
>   possible arrangements. So, the result will be (7c3) * (4c2) * 5!?

From @Andre Nicolas

> Yes, that is correct.

***Thanks to @whacka and @Andre Nicolas for their help.***

Answer (score 3):

**Outline:** We assume that you want to make $5$-letter patterns.

$1$. How many ways are there to **choose** the $3$ consonants and $2$ vowels that we will use?

$2$. For every way of choosing the letters we will use, how many ways are there to line them up in a row?

Comment: There are 7c3 ways to choose the 3 constants from 7 and 4c2 ways to choose 2 vowels from 4. To fill the 5 place, there could be 5! possible arrangements. So, the result will be (7c3) * (4c2) * 5!?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.